# Plot3D not plotting curve of intersection that sits as a single space curve right above the surface, leaving a "hole" on the surface

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to plot the following piecewise function.
$$
    f(x, y) =
    \begin{cases}
    1,  & \text{if $xy = 0 $} \\
    0, & \text{if $xy \neq 0$}
    \end{cases}
$$

This is the code I've written:

```
f[x_, y_] := Piecewise[{{1, x*y == 0}, {0, True}}]
Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]
```

This is the result I got:

[image: The graph of f(x, y)]

But the plot doesn't show the lines that are "lifted" from the surface. How do I fix this?

Comment: `Plot3D[]` is *never* going to plot any one-dimensional components by itself, so you need to do extra work like what was shown in the answers you got. (Similar considerations apply for `ParametricPlot3D[]` with two independent variables.)

Comment: @J.M.'spersistentexhaustion Thank you for pointing that out. That helps.

Answer (score 4):

One way is to find the parametric equations of the missing lines and plot them separately using `ParametricPlot3D`, then combine the plots using `Show`:

```
p1=Plot3D[Piecewise[{{1,x*y==0}, {0, True}}], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}];
p2=ParametricPlot3D[{t,0,1},{t,-10,10}];
p3=ParametricPlot3D[{0,t,1},{t,-10,10}];
Show[p1,p2,p3]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
 Show[Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10},
   PlotRange -> 3/2, BoxRatios -> 1, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False], 
 Plot3D[f[0, y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
   PlotStyle -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None, Exclusions -> None, 
   MeshFunctions -> {# #2 &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
   MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

- We set the `Exclusions Style` to any style to keep the exclusion parts.

```
f[x_, y_] := Piecewise[{{1, x*y == 0}, {0, True}}]
plot = Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
  ExclusionsStyle ->Red, 
  Exclusions -> "Discontinuities"]
```

- Then we lift the exclusion parts to `z=1`.

```
indexs = Position[plot, GraphicsGroup];
Show[Delete[plot, indexs // Last // Most],
 DeleteCases[
   Delete[plot, indexs // First // Most], _Line, -1] /. {x_Real, 
    y_Real, z_Real} :> {x, y, 1}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

- test another condition.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
f[x_, y_] := Piecewise[{{1, Cos[x] + Cos[y] == 1/2}, {0, True}}]
plot = Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
  ExclusionsStyle -> Red, Exclusions -> "Discontinuities"]
indexs = Position[plot, GraphicsGroup];
Show[Delete[plot, indexs // Last // Most], 
 DeleteCases[
   Delete[plot, indexs // First // Most], _Line, -1] /. {x_Real, 
    y_Real, z_Real} :> {x, y, 1}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: `f[x_, y_] = Piecewise[{{1, Cos[x] + Cos[y] - 1/2 == 0}, {0, True}}];
plot = Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
   ExclusionsStyle -> None];
curves = 
  Plot3D[1, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
   MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y}, Cos[x] + Cos[y] - 1/2], 
   Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshStyle -> Red, PlotStyle -> None, 
   BoundaryStyle -> None];
Show[plot, curves, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]`